# AWS - Single email notification for multiple ObjectCreate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, object-create

I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate multiple ObjectCreate() events into a single email notification instead of one email notification for each.

I would also like to send it to the client once per day as a sort of daily update for each changed file that day.

Is there a built-in way to accomplish this or do I need to write some code?

Thanks!

Comment: Just off the top of my head - and hence not worth a full answer - but keep the state for notification in DynamoDB i.e. "1 or more ObjectCreate() have been received", then triggering an SNS once a day (i.e. scheduled trigger in Lambda) to send out the email? EDIT: the Lambda function would also reset your DynamoDB state table.

Comment: When you say "CreateObject() events", are you referring to events being generated due to objects being created in an Amazon S3 bucket?